# pandas will not let me reindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a function to more easily manipulate similar data sets, but for some reason the function is not reindexing my data frame. Could someone tell me what is going on? I am trying to figure out how to reindex and interpolate the data and am wondering why it stops there.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
data2.rename(columns={'DATE':'DATE','DGS20':'Yd'},inplace = True)
data.rename(columns={'DATE':'DATE','DGS10':'Yd'},inplace = True)

def func(dat):

    dat.DATE = pd.to_datetime(dat.DATE)
    dat.Yd = pd.to_numeric(dat.Yd,errors = "coerce")

    dat.index = dat.DATE
    dat.drop('DATE',axis = 1,inplace = True)

    scale = pd.date_range(start = data.index[0],end = data.index[3774],freq = 'D') 
    dat = dat.reindex(scale) <--- THIS LINE IS NOT EXECUTING

    dat.interpolate(method = 'time',inplace = True)
```

RESULT:

The function works, but the manipulation is stopping at the line I have pointed out above.

SAMPLE OF DATA:

```
DATE,DGS5
2004-01-02,3.36
2004-01-05,3.39
2004-01-06,3.26
2004-01-07,3.25
2004-01-08,3.24
2004-01-09,3.05
2004-01-12,3.04
2004-01-13,2.98
2004-01-14,2.96
2004-01-15,2.97
2004-01-16,3.03
2004-01-19,.
2004-01-20,3.05
2004-01-21,3.02
2004-01-22,2.96
2004-01-23,3.06
2004-01-26,3.13
2004-01-27,3.07
2004-01-28,3.22
2004-01-29,3.22
2004-01-30,3.17
2004-02-02,3.18
2004-02-03,3.12
2004-02-04,3.15
2004-02-05,3.21
2004-02-06,3.12
2004-02-09,3.08
2004-02-10,3.13
2004-02-11,3.03
2004-02-12,3.07
2004-02-13,3.01
2004-02-16,.
2004-02-17,3.02
2004-02-18,3.03
2004-02-19,3.02
2004-02-20,3.08
2004-02-23,3.03
2004-02-24,3.01
2004-02-25,2.98
2004-02-26,3.01
2004-02-27,3.01
2004-03-01,2.98
2004-03-02,3.04
2004-03-03,3.06
2004-03-04,3.02
2004-03-05,2.81
2004-03-08,2.74
2004-03-09,2.68
2004-03-10,2.71
2004-03-11,2.72
2004-03-12,2.73
2004-03-15,2.74
2004-03-16,2.65
2004-03-17,2.66
2004-03-18,2.72
2004-03-19,2.75
2004-03-22,2.69
2004-03-23,2.69
2004-03-24,2.68
2004-03-25,2.70
2004-03-26,2.81
2004-03-29,2.86
2004-03-30,2.86
2004-03-31,2.80
2004-04-01,2.87
2004-04-02,3.15
2004-04-05,3.24
2004-04-06,3.19
2004-04-07,3.19
2004-04-08,3.22
2004-04-09,.
2004-04-12,3.26
2004-04-13,3.37
2004-04-14,3.44
2004-04-15,3.45
2004-04-16,3.39
2004-04-19,3.42
2004-04-20,3.45
2004-04-21,3.52
2004-04-22,3.46
2004-04-23,3.58
2004-04-26,3.57
2004-04-27,3.52
2004-04-28,3.60
2004-04-29,3.66
2004-04-30,3.63
2004-05-03,3.63
2004-05-04,3.66
2004-05-05,3.71
2004-05-06,3.72
2004-05-07,3.96
2004-05-10,3.95
2004-05-11,3.94
2004-05-12,3.96
2004-05-13,4.01
2004-05-14,3.92
2004-05-17,3.83
2004-05-18,3.87
2004-05-19,3.93
2004-05-20,3.86
2004-05-21,3.91
2004-05-24,3.90
2004-05-25,3.89
2004-05-26,3.81
2004-05-27,3.74
2004-05-28,3.81
2004-05-31,.
2004-06-01,3.86
2004-06-02,3.91
2004-06-03,3.89
2004-06-04,3.97
2004-06-07,3.95
2004-06-08,3.96
2004-06-09,4.01
2004-06-10,4.00
2004-06-11,.
2004-06-14,4.10
2004-06-15,3.90
2004-06-16,3.96
2004-06-17,3.93
2004-06-18,3.94
2004-06-21,3.91
2004-06-22,3.92
2004-06-23,3.90
2004-06-24,3.85
2004-06-25,3.85
2004-06-28,3.97
2004-06-29,3.92
2004-06-30,3.81
2004-07-01,3.74
2004-07-02,3.62
2004-07-05,.
2004-07-06,3.65
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, its just not reindexing the data and also not interpolating

Comment: can you please share a sample of your dataframe, so that to re-produce your problem?

Comment: On the line in question (`dat = dat.reindex(scale)`), you overwrite _the parameter_, not the original DataFrame or Series. The function works, but you never return the results. Add `return dat` at the end and use the returned value in the caller.

Comment: what do you mean my "use the returned value in the caller"? when I return dat, it does not overwrite dat, it just returns it

Comment: data has been added @DYZ

Comment: You overwrite the parameter in the function, on the line that you claim does not work. The calculated reindexed dataframe is never returned from the function and is lost. You to return it.

Answer (score 0):

From the v0.23.4 [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex):

> DataFrame.reindex supports two calling conventions
>   
>       `(index=index_labels, columns=column_labels, ...)
>       (labels, axis={'index', 'columns'}, ...)`
>
> We *highly* recommend using keyword arguments to clarify your intent.

EDIT: The following code works for me. I added a `return` statement in my function.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_series = {'Yd': [3.36, 3.39, 3.26, 3.25, 3.24, 3.05, 3.04, 2.98, 2.96, 2.97, 3.03, '.']}
raw_index = ['2004-01-02', '2004-01-05', '2004-01-06', '2004-01-07', '2004-01-08', '2004-01-09', '2004-01-12', '2004-01-13', '2004-01-14', '2004-01-15', '2004-01-16', '2004-01-19']

dat = pd.DataFrame(raw_series, index=raw_index)

def func(dat):
    dat.loc[:, 'Yd'] = pd.to_numeric(dat['Yd'], errors="coerce")
    dat.index = pd.to_datetime(dat.index)

    scale = pd.date_range(raw_index[0], raw_index[-1], freq='D')
    reindexed = dat.reindex(index=scale)
    return reindexed.interpolate(method='time')
```

Output:

```
            Yd
2004-01-02  3.360000
2004-01-03  3.370000
2004-01-04  3.380000
2004-01-05  3.390000
2004-01-06  3.260000
2004-01-07  3.250000
2004-01-08  3.240000
2004-01-09  3.050000
2004-01-10  3.046667
2004-01-11  3.043333
2004-01-12  3.040000
2004-01-13  2.980000
2004-01-14  2.960000
2004-01-15  2.970000
2004-01-16  3.030000
2004-01-17  3.035000
2004-01-18  3.040000
2004-01-19  3.045000
2004-01-20  3.050000
```

verify the data types:

```
>>>func(dat).reset_index().dtypes

index    datetime64[ns]
Yd              float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: data has been added @ralex

Comment: Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, please give sample data as code.